# Why am I getting a NullPointerException with this array?

Tags: arrays, nullpointerexception

So I've created this simple Class called cell:

```
public class Cell {

    public String toString() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

and I've initialized an array of cells with this line:

```
Cell[][] cellArray = new Cell[7][10];
```

so why do I get a NullPointerException when I call values in the cell like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<7; j++) {
        System.out.println(cellArray[j][i].toString());
    }
}
```

and how can I check if there is nothing in a particular index of an array without getting an exception? Would i simply use a try/catch block?

Comment: Have you initialized cellArray[j][i] ?

Comment: Where are you initializing each array element?

Answer (score 0):

You have created the array, however it have never actually been initialized anywhere. You are getting a `NullPointer`, because the newly created array has nothing within.

Here is a short loop to initialize your 2d array.

```
for i = 0 to 6
    for j = 0 to 9
        cellArray[i][j] = new Cell();
```